# Quartz Scheduler CronExpression unexpected calculation

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net, quartz

I'm using Quartz.Net and I add my jobs with CronExpression.
When I added the expression (0 */9 * ? * * *) for per 9 minute, quartz triggered correct minutes in only the hour of first firing.

My expectation, if first fire time is 21:45 then next fire time would be 21:54 - 22:05 etc.
But, as you could see the image, after 21:54, next fire time been 22:00.  It makes same calculating for every hour. (you can see what I mean in image)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP76j.png)

What kind of cronexpression that I need?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you get 22:05 from, because this is neither 9 minutes after 21:54 or 22:00 (21:54 + 9 minutes is 22:03 and 22:00 + 9 minutes is 22:09).

I don't think Quartz's Cron Trigger really supports running a different schedule every hour. Using */9 seems to be the same as 0/9. This means start at 0 minutes past the hour and then every 9 minutes after that to the end of the hour. This gives 00, 09, 18, 27, 36, 45 and 54 minutes past each hour, which is exactly what you are getting. Because 60 does not divide exactly by 9 (it has a remainder of 6) you are getting a run at the end of the hour that only has a 6 minute gap.

If you are just trying to get it to run every 9 minutes from when it starts you probably want [Simple Trigger](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html#simpletrigger-misfire-instructions) rather than a [Cron Trigger](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html#example-cron-expressions).